# Split a list at an odd location

Tags: python

I need to split this list at each space followed by a number. The number is a string in the list, though.

```
data_listtrial[2].split(' ')
['TransAtlantic', 'Petroleum', 'Ltd', '1.57', '99.86']
```

In the above, I'd like 'TransAtlantic' and 'Petroleum' and 'Ltd' to end up as one element in the list. Whereas the data '1.57' and '99.86' should each be their own element.

Before I split on spaces, the list looks like list:

```
('TransAtlantic Petroleum Ltd 1.57 99.86')
```

Is my regex knowledge lacking?

Best, 
Rudolf

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: A list with three elements.  ['TransAtlantic Petroleum Ltd', '1.57', '99.86']

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To split a string at each space followed by a number, you can use `re.split` with a lookahead pattern:

```
import re
s = 'TransAtlantic Petroleum Ltd 1.57 99.86'
re.split(r' (?=\d)', s)
```

This returns:

```
['TransAtlantic Petroleum Ltd', '1.57', '99.86']
```

Comment: Thanks, blhsing. This is a more exact answer as opposed to TigerhawkT3's workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `str.rsplit` to split from the right, and specify a `maxsplit` to leave the company name intact:

```
>>> s = 'TransAtlantic Petroleum Ltd 1.57 99.86'
>>> s.rsplit(maxsplit=2)
['TransAtlantic Petroleum Ltd', '1.57', '99.86']
```